# Rolling back changes in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am using Notepad++. By mistakely I made a change in all the files in my desktop. I used replace in find in files options and gave it the path D:\Users\vndratosnb\Desktop which replaced the data of all the files on my desktop.Can some1 help me to rollback this??

Comment: I am unable to restore to previous version as I am unable to see any in the previous version tab.

Comment: The issue is this a virtual desktop and I am using it through VMware. can you please guide something else

Comment: Primarily "hope based".

Answer (score 0):

Using Notepad++, can simply just try `UNDO`? ( I am sure that is the first thing you tried ).

If not, I am afraid that, *unless you have file system backups somewhere*, you have essentially just applied a lossless filter to all those files;

There would be no retrieving what was lost; as the blocks on disk have already been overwritten by the new, altered data of each file.

---

Future Prevention

In Windows (7and above), Microsoft has implemented a service called File History which will track, and allow you to roll back individual changes to each file. This has to be enabled per directory / block device.

Answer (score 0):

By replacing files in the desktop, you have rewritten these files. Even data recovery softwares can't recover them cause they are gone for good. If you moved those files from another partition, you can try to recover them by using data recovery apps. You will be lucky if they weren't rewritten.